# Is there a way in TypeScript to declare that a function will definitely define a variable?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a class in TypeScript that doesn't compute all the information it can contain until it's first requested but caches it after that. The logic basically boils down to this.

```
let foo: string | undefined = undefined;
function defineVariables(): void {
    foo = "foo";
}
function getFoo(): string {
    if (!foo) {
        defineVariables();
    }
    return foo; // type "string | undefined" not assignable to type "string"
}
```

As the comment I've added notes, this results in an error because the compiler can't tell that after `defineVariables()` has been called, `foo` will definitely  no longer be `undefined`. Is there a way to declare for the compiler that this is the case, or will this sort of goal require a different design? I've tried to Google the issue but having "declare", "function" and "variable" in the question muddies the results a lot.

As a side note, obviously, in this simplified example this design is pointless, but imagine that `defineVariables()` does a bunch of calculation and defines multiple variables, and `getFoo()` has cause to be called many times.

Edit: With respect to @ksav's reply, `return foo as string;` suppresses the error, but I'm not sure if it solves the root of the problem, and I'm curious if there's something I could do in the `defineVariables()` that would be more correct.

Comment: Either `foo`'s type is `string`, or `getFoo`'s return type is `string | undefined`.

Comment: @ksav The point of the design is that `foo` isn't initially defined, so it has to be `string | undefined`, but `getFoo` will make sure it's defined and then return it, so it will always return a `string`.

Comment: I guess you can cast it in the return statement -  `return foo as string;`

Comment: As ksav had pointed out, the 2 types are not the same string != (String | undefined). An easy fix would be to remove the undefine part from the variable and introduce a new variable isInitialised. It also makes for better reading since currently foo holds two purposes namely 'are variables initialised' and the actual value. How would this code behave when the initialised value of foo is undefined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of your problem here is that you're depending on side effects, rather than on function return types. Typescript has a hard time with side effects (and they are more prone to bugs).

You have a few ways you could solve this:

1. You could just `return foo as string` to indicate that you are declaring that foo will definitely be a string at that point. This is simple, but you're basically just overriding Typescript, so you could break your code in the future if you manage to break the codepath where foo is set.
2. At runtime, you can assert that foo is a defined value, or throw an exception otherwise:

```js
let foo: string | undefined = undefined;
function defineVariables(): void {
    foo = "foo";
}
function getFoo(): string {
    if (!foo) {
        defineVariables();
    }
    if (foo) {
        return foo;
    }
    throw new Error("Foo failed to define");
}
```

This works, but it introduces more overhead at runtime, and it won't catch errors at compile time if `defineVariables()` were changed to not guarantee foo's definition.

Or:

3. My personal recommendation: refactor your code so that you deal with return values rather than side effects:

```js
let foo: string | undefined = undefined;
function defineVariables(): string {
    foo = "foo";
    // and whatever else here
    return foo;
}

function getFoo(): string {
    if (!foo) {
        return defineVariables();
    }
    return foo;
}
```

This is obviously a redundant example with just the one variable defined, but it narrows the scope of your usage of `foo` in `getFoo` down to a context where it will always be inferrable to be not undefined.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I'm happy to accept this answer since it answers the question as I wrote it, but I'd like to ask a follow-up question on a complication relevant to my use case. Let's say I have two variables, `foo` and `bar` which are both derived from the same time-consuming process. If I had `getOrDefineFoo` and `getOrDefineBar` separately it would defeat the point of this design since I'd have to run that process twice. Is there a way to make `getOrDefineFooAndBar()` that I can run once and still get both results through return values?

Comment: I may have rubber ducked into this answer, actually. The second time I run `getOrDefineFooAndBar()` its values will already be calculated and it can just return `{foo, bar}` without further calculation. Thanks again for the answer, accepting.

Comment: Yup, exactly. This is a technique called memoization. The general idea is just "if this is defined, just return it. Else, run some expensive operation, save the result to variables, and return it. Either way, it gets returned."

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using an `asserts` return type. Note that I've moved the `if` statement from the getter to the initialiser, since Typescript is not quite smart enough to do the control-flow narrowing properly otherwise.

```
class Foo {
    private foo: string | undefined = undefined;

    public getFoo(): string {
        this.ensureFoo();
        return this.foo;
    }

    private ensureFoo(): asserts this is Record<'foo', string> {
        if(!this.foo) {
            this.foo = 'bar';
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ0PQA4CcCWAbmAC4Cm0AZogFzQTH4B2A5tAD7QCujAJqRXkake0ALxde-QcIDcqdJiycARiDzBozUsQTwAFAEpa9JqzSYL0YgAs8EAHSlGETjlK7Dcy5jfFXjK1sHKngvTABfeQtcQhJyJxc3DyNoSAhSHGIYGztoXIAlUmB4HB4AHgByEIqAGjoGQWYAPhQFbzwKPQBCHODEA1bvb177ELFoCuUwHAqw70iLSMigA)